# How to set DataTemplate for class inheriting more than one interface?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to use an MVVM architecture and MEF in order to build by application. I want to use `DataTemplates` and `ContentControls` in order to allow my application to display to the user in as generic a way as possible.

So I am now creating the ability for a user to read/write information and read/write results to somewhere, could be XML, could be a database. So I have two interfaces `IResultStorage` and `ITestStorage`

I now want to create a page for the user to update settings for these, so file location or database etc. My view model imports them via MEF:

```
public sealed class AdminViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [Import]
    public ITestStorage TestStorage { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public IResultStorage ResultStorage { get; set; }
}
```

Then the view is exported and loaded into the `Resources.MergedDictionaries` at run time

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AdminViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0">
            <TabItem Header="Tests">
                <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding TestStorage}"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Results">
                <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding ResultStorage}"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, the way I currently have it implemented is that one class has inherited both of these and it is this that is causing me problems:

```
[Export(typeof(ITestStorage))]
[Export(typeof(IResultStorage))]
public sealed class XmlStorage : ITestStorage, IResultStorage { ... }
```

So when the `AdminViewModel` above gets drawn both `ContentControls` are of type `XmlStorage` it seems so I don't know how to create `DataTemplates` to draw them properly.

Hopefully this makes sense, if I have done it totally the wrong way it would be good to know.

Comment: Hmm, it's totally correct, that both `ContentControls` contain a `XmlStorage`. Since you don't have separate templates for the interfaces, why should the view show anything different?

Comment: @DHN I did create a template for the `IResultStorage` but it didn't take effect although I do seem to recall that you cannot create a `DataTemplate` for an interface? So all that said it might be that what I though of doing is not possible and requires 2 separate classes derived individually from the interfaces in order to do it? I was hoping there was some clever trickery instead

Comment: Pls refer to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Well for a more *tricky* implementation, let us called it *more intelligent implementation* I would suggest a `TemplateSelector`. For more information please have look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

You will be able to assign templates based on the type of the given VM or business object. The only challenge you will face is the fact that you have to find out in which 'role' the object is passed to the `TemplateSelector`.

**Additional info**

I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx) will help you, too.

Answer (score 1):

have you testet if you create subDatatemplates for each as Resourse?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TestStorage}">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding someValueFromTestStorage}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

EDIT

maybe this 2 links could help you [First](http://www.dev102.com/2008/04/23/wpf-datatemplate-for-interfaces-not-supported/), [Second (ger)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/wpfde/thread/8bc0431e-dc9f-40dd-b4c6-6866e524b8e5/)

also this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1e774a24-0deb-4acd-a719-32abd847041d/) could be interesting follow **Beatriz Costa - MSFT (Partner)**

Comment: Since `TestStorage` is a property and not a type your suggestion won't work. ;o)